# OS Storage not release after move data file in Oracle 12c

Tags: linux, oracle, storage, oracle12c, rhel

Today I try to move oracle data file online as we know that is a capability from Oracle 12c. But after Im moving some data file, why my mount point still give me 100% of usage?

```
[oracle@DB myserver]$ df -h /oracle/oradata1/
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_oradata1-lv_oradata1  296G  281G   21M 100% /oracle/oradata1
[oracle@DB myserver]$
[oracle@DB myserver]$ du -sh /oracle/oradata1/
151G    /oracle/oradata1/
```

it supposed to be I have more than 100GB free space in my /oradata1

I also check the data file in the old mount point oradata1 already moved to oradata2. But why my OS(rhel 6.5) Storage not releasing the size?

Can someone give me some clue for this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't that telling you the used space has decreased from 281G to 151G? That *is* more than 100GB free... am I missing something? Does `df` show something different?

Comment: Hi Alex, what I mean is my mount point oradata1 size should be 151GB (using du -sh /oradata1). But somehow it always give me 281GB when I using df -h.

Comment: If I understand what you mean, it sounds like a process still has the original file open. It might be helpful to edit your question to show the current df output, the exact commands you ran in Oracle, and your full version and patch level.

Comment: @AlexPoole here you go buddy..I already edited the detail thx

Comment: You still haven't shown the commands you ran to move the data file?

Comment: @AlexPoole Im using this query ALTER DATABASE MOVE DATAFILE '/u01/oracle/rbdb1/user1.dbf'   TO '/u01/oracle/rbdb1/user01.dbf'; 
I get from https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/dfiles.htm#ADMIN11430

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer from another forum and redhat

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2316

lsof and find the pid.

Thanks